# Google Cloud Persistent Disk Backup Strategy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are working on setting up a GPC environment with some Windows servers.  Traditional backup is to backup our data daily.  I know that I can run a disk snapshot.

```
gcloud compute --project=projectid disks snapshot diskname --zone=zonename --snapshot-names=snapshotname
```

I also understand that the snapshot is a forever incremental snapshot.  However, I want an ability to schedule this.  I am not sure what the best approach is for this.  I am not sure if this is even the best way to do this.

I appreciate any guidance in regards to do backups of instances.  I have this created in AWS using Lambda I am just not sure how to do this in GPC.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine can [schedule tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron). You could use this to invoke a function running in a GAE app that calls the snapshot API.

Answer (score 0):

You can now set snapshot schedule to backup persistent disks.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots